# AndroidStudio record Espresso test

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm trying the new AndroidStudio 2.2 "Record Espresso test" tool.
(Run -> Record Espresso test).

From what I understand this tool records every interaction and convert them to a single test file. What if I need multiple files, one for every activity I'm interacting with? Is this possible?
Is there a way to record only one target activity instead of go through the whole app every time?

Unfortunately there's no mention of this kind of feature in this [android blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html) and maybe the feature is no there at all but I couldn't find any information about that.

The blog post just says:

> Android Studio will capture all your UI interactions  and convert them into a fully reusable Espresso Test that you can run locally or even on Firebase Test lab.

Comment: AFAIK There is no such way to generate individual files for the each activity. One way you can do this is you run each Espresso test for each activity one  at a time only and record that. May be it can help.

Comment: It's not possible to record only a portion of the app flow. If I need to record for example an activity that I can reach only through other 3 activities, the tool records every time every interaction from the first activity 'til the last one. When you run the tool, the app starts always from the splash screen

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> Android Studio will capture all your UI interactions and convert them
>   into a fully reusable Espresso Test that you can run locally or even
>   on Firebase Test lab.

`Espresso Test Recorder` although it's already added  in `Android Studio 2.2`, it's still pretty experimental feature. Like you said in comment it allows you to record the app workflow, but you cannot record simple activity or fragment. Maybe in the nearest feature it would be added like Android TV support.

> What if I need multiple files, one for every activity I'm interacting
>   with? Is this possible?

The best way would be record app workflow and split them to the classes. Very handful might be learning basics of Espresso code using these documentation: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/index.html

I think that at this time the best way to write complete UI tests is to learn how to code, recording may help you, but it won't as it pretty naive, do the whole job.

Hope it will help.